# Arabic data is downloading in ???? mark from mysql server

Tags: android, utf-8, localization

I am trying to download Arabic data from MySql server. Now it is store in Data base in arabic, but when i try to download in Andrid then it change to question mark like this.
*I have DataBase column as **UTF-general-ci***

Answer (score 0):

Insert your PHP header:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF8');
```

Or for JSON:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF8');
```

I hope it resolves your problem.